# Did anyone predict the death of the Sun before science?

Tags: astronomy

After scientists discovered how the Sun makes energy they realized that someday it will exhaust its fusible material and go dark. But did anyone (or any nation) talk about the death of the Sun throughout history before this scientific discovery?

**Update**: I have done these searches in Google and none of them has any results that I could see for page 1 and page 2.

1. death of Sun in ancient history
2. first nation to claim that Sun will die
3. anyone in ancient Greece said that the sun will die

And for the definition of **science**, let's refer to [NASA](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/science/en/)

> Science consists of observing the world by watching, listening, observing, and recording. Science is curiosity in thoughtful action about the world and how it behaves.

**Update 2**:

I think I can phrase the question in a simpler way:

Is there any mention of the death of the sun, in any historical book?

**Update 3**:

Maybe this example would help in clarifying even more:

Ancient Greek philosophers talked about atomic theory, that the world is created from indivisible small things called atoms. They had no idea if it was true and they had no way whatsoever to test it. Yet they talked about it.

I want to find the same thing regarding the death of the Sun, (or stars in general maybe). I want to know if a nation throughout history has talked about the death of the Sun as a reality of this universe.

**Update 4**:

I'm interested only in theories predating modern empirical/research science as a whole.

Comment: Are you asking whether there was an early naturalistic (i.e., not 'eaten by the Fenris wolf') prediction of the end of the Sun before modern science? (BTW, the definition of science in the NASA quote is grossly inadequate and has little to do with how science is actually done.)

Comment: I believe the Aztecs thought the sun would eventually die. This could be postponed (but not prevented) by feeding it with the blood of sacrifices.

Comment: @NeMo, awesome. That's exactly what I search for. Do you know some solid resources for that?

Comment: Mythology SE might be a good place to ask too (but I don't know what the rules are about duplicate questions on different sites). This is more about what people believed rather than what actually happened, although of course myhts can be part of history.

Comment: Are you really asking for "modern science" as Mark Olson suggested, or that rather broad definition from NASA? If the latter, then it seems to me that you're gonna be limited to mythology. I could migrate this over to Myth.SE if you prefer.

Comment: @Semaphore, it's weird to me that you mention **modern science**. Science is a universal thing with a very clear definition. The scientific method also is very well-known to almost everyone who is familiar with the most basic experiments and verifications. I fail to understand your emphasis. sometimes we make things complex. I have asked a very simple question, and I see no reason to complicate it. Is there any reference to the death of the sun in any historical book? What about this question is complex?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati That's absolutely not true. The meaning and implication of "science" has changed throughout history, and the scientific method itself is a rather recent development. This isn't about complexity as much as I'm trying to determine if you're really interested in mythology, in which case this is better suited to be asked in Myth.SE.

Comment: @Semaphore, thank you for the help. I am not interested in mythology. For example, it's said that old Greece is the first nation that thought about atomic theory. They had no idea and no tool to measure the correctness of this hypothesis, but nevertheless, they said it. I want to see if a nation has ever talked about the death of the sun.

Comment: @OP, I've answered now. I didn't realise you wanted something outside of mythology but I hope it's interesting.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask a new question, asking who was the first person to predict the death of the sun outside of a religious context? Your analogy of Democritus and the atoms is helpful. It would be better not to edit your question at this point as it would pull the rug from under people who've already answered (I don't really mind, but others might).

Comment: I agree with you about science, by the way.

Comment: What is the basis for your assertion that the Greeks did not observe the world or engage in thoughtful action?

Comment: @MCW, this question is a classic example of the unintentional sealioning I was talking about in the meta question about the decline in questions to this stack. The guy comes and asks if anyone propounded this idea before science. Then someone asks him what science is - why is it automatically a bad thing if different answers proceed from different understandings of what science is? He gives a definition because he was asked for one, then he gets dragged into debates about it. Can you see what I'm saying here at all? I'm not trying to blame this all on you, but do you agree this is a problem?

Comment: I see your problem and I empathize.  But I tried to warn you early that there were simply too many undefined terms in your question. The reason I try to issue that warning early is that we frequently fall into a reverse sealion problem  = someone asks a question, gets an answer and replies "that's not what I meant" , so someone offers another answer and they reply, "I already knew that"  by the third iteration, tempers fray and nobody can tell what the question or the answer is anymore.

Comment: @MCW, I understand that there are rulea. There are conventions. There are protocoles. But they should not get extreme to the point that noone can benefit from the Q&A infrastructure anymore. I am an engineer, and I know what "being specific" means. But as we leafn language, we realize that we can't be 100% clear. Language is extremely complex. Anyone ever included in NLP attests that. Thus instead of being so strict to make things 10 folds harder and more complex, simply let others answer. What is difficult about that?

Comment: @MCW, intervening early is good, but with respect, that's not what you've done on this ocassion. You asked *What is the basis for your assertion that the Greeks did not observe the world or engage in thoughtful action?* Do you *really* think that the OP was saying that? Yes, I agree it's possible to put that construction on his words. However, that's because he kept editing his question in trying to keep up with people's queries

Comment: Most people would agree that Democritus's theorizing was not science, even though he was a very clever man who was closer to the money than most of his contemporaries. Most people would also agree that Fred Hoyle's Steady-state model *was* science, even though it was ultimately discredited and displaced by the Big Bang model. Many of those people wouldn't be able to give you a clear answer of what science is, but that doesn't always matter, as in this question. In this question, the querent was unnecessarily made to explicate it, did an imperfect job, & this led a lot of unnecessary problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Aztecs believed that the sun was the fifth in a line of suns, and that each of the preceding four had been destroyed before its successor was created. Various natural disasters had destroyed the previous suns. This one would be destroyed as well, by an earthquake. Its destruction could be delayed by human sacrifices, but not prevented forever. See [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40015027?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents):

> Set I. The Five Ages- War and Destruction. Duran (1971: 412) relates that
> on the walls of the Temple of Warriors within a sacred compound surrounding the Templo Mayor was a large emblem of a butterfly. He tells us that this emblem meant "ollin" or "motion." The root of the word "heart" also meant motion. In this age, not only were still-beating hearts offered as the life-blood of the universe but the warriors, when sacrificed, went to the sky to help the sun each day and, after four years, became butterflies which flitted from flower to flower.
>
> This central image suggests what appears to be the primary ordering principle of this first set - an ordering principle for time. Its basic impetus is a
> historically sequential, temporal message of eschatology - a vision of time
> with an emphasis on destruction. **The scenario presented in this story is one
> in which the original timeless unity is divided by four deities into a series
> of ages, each called a "sun." Each sun is destroyed, apparently completely,**
> for in each sun the inhabitants either "disappear" or "perish." In the fourth
> sun even the heavens collapse. **The fifth sun is begun by divine sacrifice and
> is also doomed to an inevitable destruction. There is no mention of a sixth
> age, or of any new creation in the future**, nor is there ever a return to that
> primordial age of of cosmic creation.

So this was not 'circle of life' stuff. The sun was going to be destroyed and there was no happy ending - just putting it off.

The Aztecs are a striking example because the sun was the centre of their mythology. I don't know much about mythology, but it's not uncommon for mythologies to predict the end of the world. Even myths with cyclical notions of time often depict the world recreated and destroyed forever. The Aztecs' mythology was linear, with one beginning and one final destruction of the world. Depending on how cultures conceptualize the world, this often entails the destruction of the sun. From the book of Revelation, Chapter 21:

> And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for **the first heaven and the first earth were passed away**; and there was no more sea. And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down from God out of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband.
>
> ...
>
> And I saw no temple therein: for the Lord God Almighty and the Lamb are the temple of it. And **the city had no need of the sun**, neither of the moon, to shine in it: for the glory of God did lighten it, and the Lamb is the light thereof.
>
> ...
>
> **And there shall be no night there [and] neither light of the sun**; for the Lord God giveth them light: and they shall reign for ever and ever.

Interestingly, earlier in Revelation the sun goes dark because of an earthquake - but then flares up again and burns people. I doubt it means anything, but if you want to write an alternate history in which ancient Israelites sail the Atlantic to meet the Aztecs, there's your excuse.

Read, Kay A. “The Fleeting Moment: Cosmogony, Eschatology, and Ethics in Aztec Religion and Society.” The Journal of Religious Ethics, vol. 14, no. 1, [Journal of Religious Ethics, Inc, Wiley, Blackwell Publishing Ltd], 1986, pp. 113–38, http://www.jstor.org/stable/40015027.

Answer (score 11):

In Norse mythology, the Sun, named Sól, is chased by a wolf, named Sköll or Fenrir. At the end of times ([Ragnarök](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnar%C3%B6k)), Fenrir will catch Sól and eat her. This is not great news:

> High then quotes stanza 45 of Völuspá. Next, High describes that the wolf will swallow the sun, then his brother will swallow the moon, and mankind will consider the occurrence as a great disaster resulting in much ruin. The stars will disappear. The earth and mountains will shake so violently that the trees will come loose from the soil, the mountains will topple, and all restraints will break, causing Fenrir to break free from his bonds.

Alternatively, Sól will have had a daughter before being eaten, and her daughter will replace her in the sky.

> Vafþrúðnismál stanza 45 is then quoted. The personified sun, Sól, will have a daughter at least as beautiful as she, and this daughter will follow the same path as her mother.

> In stanza 46, Odin asks what sun will come into the sky after Fenrir has consumed the sun that exists. Vafþrúðnir responds that Sól will bear a daughter before Fenrir assails her, and that after Ragnarök this daughter will continue her mother's path.

In yet another version, the Sun would just turn black.

> The god Freyr fights Surtr and loses. After this, people flee their homes, and the sun becomes black while the earth sinks into the sea, the stars vanish, steam rises, and flames touch the heavens.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is a useful resource and I'll look at it. But I'm more interested in a historical approach. I mean, I'm looking for some historian writing about somebody famous that talks about the sun dying at the end.

Comment: Norse traditions like Gylfaginning have of course being studied by historians, but their authors are not "somebody famous" : their names have not reached us.

Comment: The two wolves, [Sköll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skoll) and [Hati Hrodhvitnisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hati_Hrodvitnisson), would seem to signify the [two types of eclipses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenrir#Theories), solar and lunar, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Probably the first rigorous hypothesis about the source of Sun's energy is the [Helmholtz-Thompson mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Helmholtz_mechanism) (or Helmholtz-Kelvin) of gravitational contraction which predicts something like 20 million years solar lifetime.

Comment: Is that before or after "science"

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I read the link and could not find the time this mechanism has been proposed. But based on its math, I assume it's related to the scientific era of 18 or 19 century. My question is related to ancient history. Let's say a thousand years ago. Or older than that.

Comment: "The mechanism was originally proposed by Kelvin and Helmholtz in the **late nineteenth century**"  (from the cited page; emphasis added)

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I interpreted "before this scientific discovery" as before the discovery of fusion being the mechanism responsible for solar output....

Comment: @RadovanGarabík, based on the calculations, I think they also did "science". Yet their scientific results were revoked later when mankind found more evidence. Just the way Darwin's inheritance idea was superseded by Mendelian inheritance or Newtonian gravity by Einstein's gravity.